# How to check that AES-NI is supported by my CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu

How can I check if my CPU supports the [AES-NI instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) under Linux/UNIX.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Look in `/proc/cpuinfo`. If you have the `aes` flag then your CPU has AES support.

You can use this command:

```
grep aes /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you have some output, which will be like

> flags     : a bunch of flags **aes** another bunch of flags

, then you have AES.

Comment: could someone test that having a cpu that has aes-ni? e.g.: what is the exact output? grep aes /proc/cpuinfo OR grep aes-ni /proc/cpuinfo ? thank you!

Comment: @Lance I'm not sure if AES and AES-NI are two different things. They look the same for me. Maybe you can see the other flags in /proc/cpuinfo.

Comment: @LanceBaynes Yes, I can confirm with a i5 cpu. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HfFxm.png)

Comment: Mind you, this only works on linux though.

Comment: Official Intel documentation does not recommend this though - https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/AES-NI_Java_Linux_Testing_Configuration_Case_Study.pdf

Comment: Note: there will be one line of output for each core that your processor has.

Answer (score 17):

There's also the [`cpuid`](http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html) utility available on a number of OS's.

```
cpuid | grep -i aes
  AES instruction                         = true
```

Comment: Not sure why this is not the accepted answer. Intel documentation recommends this too - https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/AES-NI_Java_Linux_Testing_Configuration_Case_Study.pdf

Comment: It's probably not the accepted answer because this answer was born much later than when the OP marked the current accepted answer.  You can vote it up, though.  If enough upvotes happen, this answer will bubble up towards the top.

Comment: `cpuid` isn't available on every platform, for example, Android.

Comment: This worked for me on FreeBSD.

Comment: Again, how to see the difference between AES and AES-NI (New Instructions)?

Answer (score 9):

Here's [the list](https://ark.intel.com/Search/FeatureFilter?productType=processors&AESTech=true). There are 247 CPU models with that feature. With Linux, you can check by looking for the aes flag in /proc/cpuinfo. Or you can check what model you have against this list.

Comment: That list doesn't include processors from other vendors though, such as AMD, Via, etc.

Comment: A list including other vendors would be most helpful.

Comment: I can only see "AES New Instructions" as a filterable option, which only shows 2022Q1 and newer.

Comment: I am an idiot... "NI" = "New Instructions" - Doh!

Answer (score 3):

```
 model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5630  @ 2.53GHz
```

with AES-NI support from Intel ark list

```
$ grep aes /proc/cpuinfo
flags: ***** aes *****
```